# postgreSQL hot_standby pg_dump on slave

Tags: postgresql, replication, backup, pg-dump

I have master-slave (hot_standby) pgsql configuration and I want to make backups from one of my slaves. I don't want PITR, just good old database dump.

I switched to postgres from MySQL. With MySQL replication I made backups from **slave** with these steps:

1. `stop slave;`
2. perform `mysqldump`
3. `start slave`

Can I do something similar with postgres?

---

I tried `pg_dump` on slave, but it returned errors:

```
pg_dump: Dumping the contents of table "news_event" failed:   PQgetResult() failed.
pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
DETAIL:  User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.
```

Also, `pg_dump` works good on master so I can do backups on master server, but I prefer to make it on slave.

Answer (score 4):

Just run `pg_dump`.  The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html) says:

> `pg_dump` is a utility for backing up a PostgreSQL database. It makes
>   consistent backups even if the database is being used concurrently.
>   `pg_dump` does not block other users accessing the database (readers
>   or writers).

In turn, the state of the database that you see on the slave is also consistent.  If there is a considerable delay in replication, the result may be slightly different than a dump from the master.

Comment: I tried it, but it works only on master. On slave I'm getting errors. Is there any ways to fix it? (I updated my question)

Comment: @Antonio: you need to tell us which error you get. If the standby is configured as a "hot standby". You might want to enable the `hot_standby_feedback`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-replication.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: error is described in the end of my question.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this e-mail thread](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/5620FD15.60302@aklaver.com) it appears dumping from slaves requires [PostgreSQL v9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hot-standby.html) and with the `hot_standby_feedback` setting (and possibly other settings) enabled. Hopefully it'll get easier/simpler as replication improves with newer versions.

Comment: From which version?  I cannot figure this out from the thread.  You are right with the `hot_standby_feedback` - without it it _may_ work but there's no guarantee.

Comment: Earliest reference I found in the documentation is v9.1. Updated answer with that link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) to perform pg_dump operation and choose what exactly should be in backup file(tables, schemas). Moreover you can choose backup settings such as backup file format. It's very easy to use, if database is big You just wait until process will finish.

To start backup after connecting to PostgreSQL just right click on database and choose **Backup...** option. Then choose right options for You and start backup process.